# How use object of []struct in golang

Tags: go, struct, slice

I defined struct like:

```
type json-input []struct {
    Data    string  `json:"data"`
}
```

that Unmarshal json string like

> [{"data":"some data"}, {"data":"some data"}]

```
data := &json-input{}
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp.Data), data)
```

How i can use object of this struct for turn of data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use hyphens in type declarations, and you probably want to unmarshal to `resp` instead of `resp.Data`; that is, you may want to do something like

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type jsoninput []struct {
    Data string `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    resp := `[{"data":"some data"}, {"data":"some more data"}]`
    data := &jsoninput{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(resp), data)
    for _, value := range *data {
        fmt.Println(value.Data)  // Prints "some data" and "some more data"
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/giDsPzgHT_